# Load a single related object

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, lazy-loading

I need to load a single related object from an navigation property (ICollection) to send to my MVC View.

This can save me from unnecessary db access and load.

I've found [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/01/31/using-dbcontext-in-ef-feature-ctp5-part-6-loading-related-entities.aspx) about loading related objects but didn't figure out how to load one single related object from the list.

To be short, I need the object and inside its navigation property one single related object.

How to achive this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do this using Include. Include will bring back all related entities for the navigation property. You can either write two separate queries or write a join in your query.

Writing two queries:

```
var princess = context.Princesses.Find(id);
var unicorns = context.Unicorns.Where(u => u.PrincessId == id && u.UnicornName == "Blinky");

princess.Unicorns = unicorns.ToList();
```